# list of dictionaries with same key,need to rewrite the column with rows returning the values with key column name

Tags: pandas, dictionary, data-processing

I am pretty new to Pandas and data preprocessing. I have got a task where I have been given a dataset which contains column where every row contains a list of dictionaries with the same key please check the image below

[image]

what I am trying to achieve is to get a **list** of the **values** of the plates for every row under a new Plates column.
which have to look like this

[image]

this is the sample data that needed to be cleaned.
candidates
"[{'plate': 'ap26tl0624'}, {'plate': 'ap26tl0624'}]"
[{'plate': '1111'}]
"[{'plate': 'ap1gth6815'}, {'plate': 'ap16th6815'}, {'plate': 'ap16thg815'}, {'plate': 'ap16thg815'}]"
[{'plate': '2gce6935'}]
"[{'plate': 'ap16tbc815'}, {'plate': 'ap1676318'}]"
"[{'plate': 'ap26ce6935'}, {'plate': 'ap26ce6935'}, {'plate': 'ap26ce6933'}, {'plate': 'ap26ce6935'}]"
"[{'plate': 'ap26ch1629'}, {'plate': 'ap26ch1629'}, {'plate': 'ap26ch1623'}, {'plate': 'ap26ch1629'}]"
"[{'plate': 'ap20185'}, {'plate': 'ai20186'}]"
[{'plate': 'br06bp5210'}]
"[{'plate': 'ap39dg9428'}, {'plate': 'ap39dg9428'}, {'plate': 'ap39dg9428'}, {'plate': 'br06bd4347'}]"
[{'plate': 'rj26ca6690'}]

can some one please have a look into this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please show what code you have so far

Comment: Hello Artyom,

this is the code I have tried so far 



res = ast.literal_eval(df.candidates)
from collections import defaultdict

mydict_ = defaultdict(list)
def function(data):
    for x in data:
        for k, v in x.items():
           mydict_[k].append(v)
function(res[2])
mydict = dict(mydict_)
print(mydict)

This is returning 

{'plate': ['ap26ce6935', 'ap26ce6935', 'ap26ce6933', 'ap26ce6935']}

and this is only for one row
Thankyou for asking

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** to answer was made to satisfy requested data format.

Please, try something as below:

```py
# generate test dataframe
df_test = pd.DataFrame([[0,[{'plate':'2323'}, {'plate':'13'}]], [1,[{'plate':'2323'}]]], columns=['ids', 'candidate'])

def get_plates(row):
    # function that returns list of plates from your data structure
    # EDITED
    if type(row['candidate']) == str:
        return [dict_value['plate'] for dict_value in eval(row['candidate'])]
    else:
        return [dict_value['plate'] for dict_value in row['candidate']]

# applying function get_plates to each row and save to column df['Plates']
df_test ['Plates'] = df_test .apply(get_plates, axis = 1)

df_test
```

[image]

Below example of function output on requested data format

```py
test_data = [
    "[{'plate': 'ap26tl0624'}, {'plate': 'ap26tl0624'}]",
    [{'plate': '1111'}],
    "[{'plate': 'ap1gth6815'}, {'plate': 'ap16th6815'}, {'plate': 'ap16thg815'}, {'plate': 'ap16thg815'}]",
    [{'plate': '2gce6935'}],
    "[{'plate': 'ap16tbc815'}, {'plate': 'ap1676318'}]",
    "[{'plate': 'ap26ce6935'}, {'plate': 'ap26ce6935'}, {'plate': 'ap26ce6933'}, {'plate': 'ap26ce6935'}]",
    "[{'plate': 'ap26ch1629'}, {'plate': 'ap26ch1629'}, {'plate': 'ap26ch1623'}, {'plate': 'ap26ch1629'}]",
    "[{'plate': 'ap20185'}, {'plate': 'ai20186'}]",
    [{'plate': 'br06bp5210'}],
    "[{'plate': 'ap39dg9428'}, {'plate': 'ap39dg9428'}, {'plate': 'ap39dg9428'}, {'plate': 'br06bd4347'}]",
    [{'plate': 'rj26ca6690'}]
]



test_data_df = pd.DataFrame(test_data, columns=['candidate'])
test_data_df['Plates'] = test_data_df.apply(get_plates, axis = 1)
test_data_df
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Artyom,
      I am getting an error ,saying TypeError: string indices must be integers , can you please help

Comment: @venupunna I have edited my code a little bit. For me it works perfectly, I need more information on your problem to assist you. please attach your samlple data and the problem directly to your question

Comment: Hi Artyom , thanks for pointing out , I have updated the question with the sample data, I hope the sampe data  will help to get clearer idea of data. the data is constructed in such a way that if there is only one plate in a row it is a simple dictionary , but in case there are more plates in a row its in string format , please check , I should have uploaded it earlier, sorry for inconvenience and delay

Comment: @venupunna please check answer now, I have made edit to satisfy your data format

Comment: worked like a charm Artyom Akselrod ,Thanks again for your patience, time and effort to answer my query , glad that stackoverflow has great people like you.